# How do I restart a C++ command prompt application?

Tags: c++

I am creating a game that will run out of a C++ command prompt.

The game is called PIG. You are playing against a computer, and your goal is to reach 100 GAME SCORE by rolling dice. If you roll a 1, your turn ends and you add nothing to your score. If you roll any other number, it gets added to your "TURN SCORE". After a roll, you have the option to roll again or to "hold". Holding adds your "TURN SCORE" to your "GAME SCORE" and passes the turn to the next player.

Everything works the way I want it to, but now I am trying to create a playagain() function that will ask the user at the end of a game if they wish to play again. If they do, the app restarts and zero's all variables. If they do not, the program exits.

Here is what I have in regards to my question:

```
if(comp_score == 100){
    char ans;
    cout << "Your opponent has reached a score of 100 and has won! Would you like to play again? [y/n] ";
    cin >> ans;
    if(ans == 'y'){
        /*restarts application and zero's all variables*/
        playagain();
    } else if(ans == 'n'){ exit(); }}
    if(play_score == 100){
    char ans;
    cout << "You have reached a score of 100 and have won! Would you like to play again? [y/n] ";
    cin >> ans;
    if(ans == 'y'){
        /*restarts application and zero's all variables*/
        playagain();
    } else if(ans == 'n'){ exit(); }
}
```

TIA!

Comment: Do you know about [`while` loops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c98k0ks.aspx)?

Comment: How can I use a `while` loop when I have multiple functions, and the game passes in between each of them? @clcto

Comment: You pass information from one function to the other: `do { /*....*/ playAgain = PromptPlayAgain(); } while( playAgain );` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO the easiest way to do this is to use a `while` loop:

```
bool keep_playing = TRUE;

while (keep_playing)
  {
  keep_playing = FALSE;

  /* zero out variables */

  /* rest of code to play the game */

  if(comp_score == 100){
      char ans;
      cout << "Your opponent has reached a score of 100 and has won! Would you like to play again? [y/n] ";
      cin >> ans;
      if(ans == 'y'){
          keep_playing = TRUE;
      } else if(ans == 'n')
      { keep_playing = FALSE; }}

  if(play_score == 100){
    char ans;
    cout << "You have reached a score of 100 and have won! Would you like to play again? [y/n] ";
    cin >> ans;
    if(ans == 'y'){
      keep_playing = TRUE;
    } else if(ans == 'n')
    { keep_playing = FALSE; }}
  }  -- while (keep_playing)...
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Seems like an appropriate case for a `do-while`, no?

Comment: @clcto: any of the looping constructs could be used. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind if your using Windows. You can use `ShellExecute` to open a new game window and give a return code of 0 to close the old one. Like this.

```
#include <windows.h>   // >>>>>>  JACOBTECH EDIT.

if(comp_score == 100){
char ans;
cout << "Your opponent has reached a score of 100 and has won! Would you like to play again? [y/n] ";
cin >> ans;
if(ans == 'y'){
    /*restarts application and zero's all variables*/
    playagain();
} else if(ans == 'n'){ exit(); }}
if(play_score == 100){
char ans;
cout << "You have reached a score of 100 and have won! Would you like to play again? [y/n] ";
cin >> ans;
if(ans == 'y'){
    ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", "C:/GameDirectory/Game.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_NORMAL);   //>>>>>>  JACOBTECH EDIT.
    return 0;  //>>>>>>  JACOBTECH EDIT.
} else if(ans == 'n'){ exit(); }
```

Cheers!